# It is ok to handle soft 404 errors with noindex, nofollow tag?

Tags: html, seo, web-crawler, robots.txt

Recently my site has experiencing lot of soft 404 errors from auto-generated menu links returning not found pages. But it will eventually filled with contents overtime, so I want to temporarily disable to search engines from crawling these pages.

(e.g. PSP > Kingdom Hearts > Cheats. It will return page with "sorry no cheats are available yet" message.)

Do you guys think this will work?

Edit: I have removed these links already from the site, but the search engines are already crawled and returning soft 404 errors.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with "soft 404 errors"? Are you still sending HTTP status 404, or do you only display an error page with a 2xx status code?

Comment: No, the page/s exists. But search engines identified it as soft 404, because the content didn't provide the useful information as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not the best practice but you might want to use redirection to 302 redirection:

The HTTP response status code 302 Found is a common way of performing a redirection. An HTTP response with this status code will additionally provide a URL in the Location header field

if it is permanent and you don't need dynamic solution use this:

you can use [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) and to Disallow search engine from getting into those urls until you will add a content to them, then open it when the pages are ready.

create robots.txt in your root directory /robots.text
and fill it with the follwing

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /cgi-bin/
Disallow: /tmp/
Disallow: /~joe/
```

Comment: I think the OP's asking for something dynamic, similar to how Wikipedia wouldn't add en.wikipedia.org/wiki/this_isnt_a_real_page to the disallow list on robots.txt.

Comment: do you think <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow"> will work too? I'm using PHP and this will be easier to implement if posible.

Comment: @user2341279 According to Emissary in a comment on my answer, "If the 404 page is served properly with a 404 code then a noindex flag in the page itself isn't necessary."

Comment: Well the page isn't served as 404. Its like search page with no possible result, that's why the search engines are returning soft 404 errors.

Comment: yes it will work too <meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">, mark the answer as correct it it helped you

Answer (score 5):

> ...from auto-generated menu links returning not found pages. But it will eventually filled with contents overtime

I would not display links which lead to non-existent pages. That these pages will "eventually filled with contents overtime" does not matter.

Apart from SEO this is also horrible user-experience: Imaging browsing a webpage, and every third link you click on returns a 404 page saying that "content will eventually filled in later". If you do not have content, don't display links to it.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that and removed the links. But search engines are already crawled these pages and returning soft 404 errors.

Comment: @user2341279 That's some crucial information you should include in your question.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include it in the question.